# How to get "initiator" debugging information for promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, promise, visual-studio-code

When debugging a `then` promise callback in Node.JS using something like Visual Studio Code, the Call Stack seems almost redundant.  Instead of providing the function that actually called my code from a logical perspective it provides the function that called my code from a literal perspective; the Bluebird library (or maybe Q library) functions.  What I actually want to see is the previous promise function that was executed, or the "initiator" of the promise chain.  From a logical perspective that is the program flow I care about.  Is there a way I can get this information during debugging?

Comment: Just so you realize, what you're asking for isn't the actual call stack.  Per promise specification, the call stack is clear of all your code when a `.then()` handler is called - that's what happens with asynchronous handlers.  That said, I understand what you would like to see (an async flow stack or something like that), but I'm not aware of any tool that will provide that.  The [Bluebird promise library](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.longstacktraces.html) has a means of giving you long stack traces which might be relevant to your problem.

Comment: Good idea.  I posted an answer.

Comment: When debugging with the Google Chrome DevTools you have already the support for an `async` call stack. What it may be on the way is the presence of some libraries (like `Bluebird`) in the stack, which you can skip using the [blackbox feature](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/blackboxing). In VSCode there's a similar feature called [`skipFiles`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_launch-configuration-attributes) you have to set in the `launch.json` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just so you realize, what you're asking for isn't the actual call stack. Per promise specification, the call stack is clear of all your code when a `.then()` handler is called - that's what happens with asynchronous handlers.

That said, I understand what you would like to see (an async flow stack or something like that), but I'm not aware of any tool that will provide that. The [Bluebird promise library](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.longstacktraces.html) has a means of giving you long stack traces which might be relevant to your problem